# Iterate over multiple dataframes and change/drop columns by partial string matches

Tags: r

I have been trying to find a way to iterate/loop over about 290 dataframes that are poorly structured. They contain the same information, but some of the column names are slightly different and some columns are blank (either with NAs or ""). I'd would like to iterate over all of them and drop columns with column names matching a particular partial string (e.g. all column names ending with numbers). I would also like to change column names if needed.

I've tried lapply, for loops, etc., and nothing works - I can't seem to find the correct syntax.

Here is an example of my attempt at lapply with grep/grepl:

```
lapply(file_list2, function(x) { x[!grepl("[0-9]")] <- NULL; x })
```

It returns the following error:

```
Error in grepl("[0-9]") : argument "x" is missing, with no default
Called from: grepl("[0-9]")
```

The file_list2 is the list of dataframe names (e.g. `a11015DEC.csv`, `a11715DEC.csv`, `a12415DEC.csv`, `a13115DEC.csv`, `a21415DEC.csv`,`a22115DEC.csv`, `a22815DEC.csv`, `a2715DEC.csv`, `a31415DEC.csv`...)

Unfortunately, I can't post actual data due to privacy concerns.

The fields (column names) are similar to the following - notice there are extraneous column names (e.g. X.1, X), which might vary slightly among the different dataframes:

```
LOCATION  X   DATE TYPE COUNTY X.1 X.2 WEIGHT RESP X.3 LEGS X.4 SKIN X.5 UNIFORM X.6 SCORE X.7 X..TYPE.SCORE X.8 X.9 X.10 X.11 X.12
```

Comment: You have to supply another argument to `grepl`. Try `lapply(file_list2, function(x) x[!grepl("[0-9]$", names(x))])`

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thanks, I must have been staring at it too long and missed that. Unfortunately, while your code doesn't throw an error, it has no effect on the dataframes and won't remove the columns.

Comment: Never mind. Went a different way, joining the dataframes, then manipulating the columns. Thanks for the response.